# Bizspark - Licensing after product goes live

Tags: bizspark

My startup is considering applying for [Microsoft BizSpark](http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/BizSpark/Pages/At_a_Glance.aspx). I am unclear as to whether or not the software is still usable after 3 years or after the product goes live (whichever comes first). My worry is that we will develop for 2 years, go to production, and all of a sudden we will not be entitled to use the software as the BizSpark agreement will be over. Thank you

Comment: Here's my confusion:

In addition to responsibility for the USD$100 program offering fee, Startups can continue to use the development tools they previously obtained through the program. If Startups wish to continue to receive updates to development tools, Startups can renew their MSDN subscription at usual rates and terms. To continue to use the production licenses, Startups may choose to take advantage of a licensing program like Microsoft’s Services Provider License Agreement program (or other Microsoft licensing programs that may be available at the time)...

Comment: I would recommend that you get an initial version of your software released "out in the wild" well before 2 years from beginning development. I don't say this because of the BizSpark program, but because the sooner you release that v1.0 release, the sooner you can start making money. Besides, your requirements are bound to change a ton in a 2 year period and you might not end up with the solution that you need. You may want to read up on Agile Software Development. Just a tip/suggestion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you exit BizSpark, you'll be required to acquire new licenses for any server software you continue to use from Microsoft, that you acquired previously through the program.

Comment: This is true, but that's after the 3 years of being in the BizSpark program. After 3 three years you should have easily been able to make enough money to be able to purchase the server software that you need.

Comment: Well, hopefully. But considering how many businesses fail within three years, those that survive should probably be able to handle it, though.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk after the 3 year program, does the startup pay for the licenses they used for the past 3 years or only pay for the licenses they are going to use thereafter?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, only the ones they'll continue to use.

Answer (score 2):

After the 3 years when you graduate from the progam, you get licenses for a substantial amount of software, entirely free.

From their FAQ on graduation:

> Keep, at no charge, all the software you downloaded during the three
>   years you were in the BizSpark program. If you have servers in
>   production, you will get licenses to continue to use up to 4 Windows
>   Servers (Standard Edition) and 2 SQL Servers (Standard Edition). The
>   BizSpark team will review requests for startups who need a different
>   configuration.

Comment: Where can I found exactly which softwares they provide the licenses after graduation?